# Is it possible to change nft metadata on solana mainnet?

Tags: nft, metadata, mainnet

I've already coded to change NFT metadata(like name, description...) in Solana devnet using candy machine v2.
But I'm not sure this really works in Solana mainnet.
Anyone who knows about this, please tell me the answer.

Comment: short answer: yes you definitely can!

Comment: thank you for your reply.
but I've got another question.
If I own once nft(for example mad_lads - the popular nft), then its mutable so I can change its metadata, right?

Comment: Only the set `update_authority` of the metadata can update it. The authority could be anything from a multi-sig to a pda authority, but it most likely won't be `your` wallet. For serious projects, it most definitely won't be.

Comment: thank you. I've got a clear idea.